# AlertDialog button not display the correct messages for the second screen

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have faced a problem where AlertDialog button not display the correct messages for the second screen.

Expected result: First screen show messages AAAAAAAAAAA in AlertDialog and
                 Second screen should show diff messages "CCCCCCC"

Problem:For the second screen it show same messages like first screen even though the messages already changes in java class.

***Below is my Tuto2Activity.java***

```
public class Tuto2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    public void open(View view){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("How to Use");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Provide a description about One BAJA in term of how to use it and benefits using it");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });


        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

          boolean checked = ( (RadioButton) view). isChecked();

           switch (view.getId()) {
               case R.id.radioButton1:
                   if (checked)
                       setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto2);
                      break;
               case R.id.radioButton2:
                   if (checked)
                       setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto3);
                   break;
               case R.id.radioButton3:
                   if (checked)
                       setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto4);
                   break;
               case R.id.radioButton4:
                   if (checked)
                       setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto5);
                   break;
               case R.id.radioButton5:
                   if (checked)
                       setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto6);

           }

    }

}
```

**Tuto3Activity.java:**

```
     public class Tuto3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto3);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }


    public void open(View view){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tuto3Activity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("How to Use");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Show the list type of vegetables and flowers and information care");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg1, int arg2) {
            }
        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }





public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

        boolean checked = ( (RadioButton) view). isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radioButton1:
                if (checked)
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto2);
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton2:
                if (checked)
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto3);
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton3:
                if (checked)
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto4);
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton4:
                if (checked)
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto5);
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton5:
                if (checked)
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuto6);

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Make your methods private and pass the correct context to it

Comment: Maybe your second class extending the first class ?

Comment: So it means change the public void to private void? Then how to pass the method?

Comment: @CagriYalcin how to check if the class is extending with another class?

Comment: It seems like that: public class Tuto3Activity extends Tuto2Activity{ } or share your all codes.

Comment: @CagriYalcin already upload a full codes

Comment: I think you are using your buttons with onClick method in .xml. Maybe you should use setOnClickListener ?

Comment: @CagriYalcin u mean no need to use on onClick in xml? Can u show the code how to change?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use onClickListener instead of onClick(in xml).

```
    Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButtonID);
    myButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Alert dialog codes...
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have changed the code, no error but the button not working.

Comment: got this error "Could not find method showDialog(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button7'"

Comment: Did you remove android:onClick ?

Comment: can you share your xml and button declaration in java ?